# Loading a kernel without a filesystem - osdev

Tags: kernel, bootloader, osdev, bochs

I built a bootloader to load my kernel onto the memory. The kernel code is lying on the sectors of the floppy. The 2 stage bootloader reads out raw bytes of memory from the floppy disk and places it on the memory and executes the kernel. This works good on the bochs emulator but fails on the qemu emulator.

Some tutorials out there suggest keeping the kernel file on a file system (like FAT12) and then reading the file from it.
So, I want to ask that would such a system actually work on a physical machine, or would it fail like on the qemu emulator? Also is it good to read the kernel this way?

*I might in future implement a filesystem in C, instead of doing it in a bootloader using assembly*

*The problem with qemu might have arised due to the fact that my image file isn't a multiple of 512 bytes, making the last sector unreadable*

**EDIT:**
The stage one bootloader successfully loads the 2nd stage on both Qemu and Bochs.
The Stage 1 bootloader is-

```
[org 0x7c00]

STAGE2 equ 0x800

STAGE2_SECTORS equ 2+1
TRACKS equ 2

mov [BOOT_DRIVE],dl

mov bp,0x9000
mov sp,bp

mov bx, msgReal
call print_string

call load_stage2

call STAGE2

jmp $

%include 'boot/bios.ASM'

[bits 16]
load_stage2:
    mov bx, msgStage2
    call print_string
    mov cl, 2
    mov bx, STAGE2
    mov dh, 1
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
load_sector:
    call disk_load
    cmp cl, STAGE2_SECTORS
    je loaded
    cmp cl, 15
    add cl, 1
    add bx, 512
    jmp load_sector
loaded:
    ret

BOOT_DRIVE db 0
msgReal db "Booted in 16-bit mode",0
msgStage2 db "Loading the stage2 boot loader onto memory",0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

The Stage 2 bootloader is-

```
[org 0x800]

KERNEL equ 0x1000
KERNEL_SECTORS equ 24

mov bx, msgStage2
call print_string

call load_kernel

mov bx, msg
call print_string

int 0x12
mov [0x600], ax

call switch_to_pm

%include 'boot/bios.ASM'

%include 'boot/gdt.ASM'
%include 'boot/protected_mode.ASM'
%include 'boot/print32.ASM'

[bits 16]

load_kernel:
    mov bx, msgKernel
    call print_string
    mov ax, 3
    mov cl, 4
    mov ch, 0
    mov bx, KERNEL
    mov dl, [BOOT_DRIVE]
    mov dh, 0
    mov ch, 0
load_sector:
    mov ah, 0x02
    mov al, 1
    int 0x13
    jc error1
    cmp al, 1
    jne error2
    push bx
    mov bl, [Sector]
    cmp bl, KERNEL_SECTORS
    pop bx
    je loaded
    push bx
    mov bl, [Sector]
    inc bl
    mov [Sector], bl
    pop bx
    inc cl
    cmp cl, 18
    jne continue
    add ch, 1
    mov cl, 1
continue:
    add bx, BytesPerSector
    jmp load_sector
loaded:
    ret

error1:
    mov bx, errorMsg1
    call print_string
    jmp $

error2:
    mov bx, errorMsg2
    call print_string
    jmp $

[bits 32]

BEGIN_PM:
    mov ebx, msgProt
    call print_string32
    call KERNEL
    jmp $

BytesPerSector equ 512
NumHeads equ 2
SectorsPerTrack equ 18

Sector db 0

BOOT_DRIVE db 0
msgStage2 db "Stage 2 reached!", 0
msgProt db "Successfully switched to 32-bit mode",0
msgKernel db "Loading the kernel onto memory",0
msg db "Loaded!!", 0
errorMsg1 db "Error1", 0
errorMsg2 db "Error2", 0

times 1024-($-$$) db 0
```

**bios.asm**:

```
[bits 16]

print_string:
    pusha
    mov cx,bx
    mov ah,0x0e
    printStringStart:
    mov al,[bx]
    cmp al,0
    je done
    int 0x10
    inc bx
    jmp printStringStart
    done:
    popa
    ret

disk_load:
    pusha
    push dx
    mov ah,0x02
    mov al,dh
    mov dh,0x0
    int 0x13
    jc disk_error
    pop dx
    cmp dh,al
    jne disk_error
    popa
    ret

disk_error:
    mov ah,0x0e
    mov al,'X'
    int 0x10
    mov bx,errMsg
    call print_string
    jmp $

errMsg:
    db "Disk Read Error....."
    times 80-20 db " "
    db 0
```

**protected_mode.asm:**

```
[bits 16]
switch_to_pm:
    cli
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm

[bits 32]
init_pm:
    mov ax, DATA_SEG
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp,0x90000
    mov esp,0x90000

    call BEGIN_PM
```

**print32.asm:**

```
[bits 32]

VIDEO_MEM equ 0xb8000
DEF_COLOR equ 0x0f

print_string32:
    pusha
    mov edx,VIDEO_MEM

print_string32_loop:
    mov al, [ebx]
    mov ah, DEF_COLOR

    cmp al,0
    je print_string32_end

    mov [edx],ax

    inc ebx
    add edx,2
    jmp print_string32_loop

print_string32_end:
    popa
    ret
```

**gdt.asm:**

```
gdt_start:
gdt_null:
    dd 0x0
    dd 0x0

gdt_code:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

**MakeFile**

```
DIRECTORIES = boot kernel drivers HALx86 dataman

C_SOURCES = $(wildcard drivers/*.c HALx86/*.c dataman/*.c)
ASM_SOURCES = $(wildcard HALx86/*.asm)

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -DDEBUG -m32 -ffreestanding -c -nostdlib

KERNEL = kernel/kernel_start.o kernel/kernel.o

ASM = nasm
AOFLAGS = -f elf32 -o
ABINFLAGS = -f bin -o

OBJ = ${C_SOURCES:.c=.o}
ASMOBJ = ${ASM_SOURCES:.asm=.o}

all: os-image.img

os-image.img: boot/boot_sector.bin boot/boot_stage2.bin kernel/kernel.bin
    cat $^ > $@
    echo "OS Image size:"
    wc -c os-image.img

kernel/kernel.bin: $(KERNEL) ${OBJ} ${ASMOBJ}
    ld -melf_i386 -o $@ -Ttext 0x1000 $^ --oformat binary

%.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o : %.asm
    $(ASM) $< $(AOFLAGS) $@

%.bin : %.asm 
    nasm $< $(ABINFLAGS) $@

clean:
    rm -fr kernel/*.o
    rm -fr drivers/*.o
    rm -fr HALx86/*.o
    rm -fr dataman/*.o
    rm -fr boot/*.bin
    rm -fr os-image.img *.bin *.o

rebuild:
    make clean
    make

backup:
    make clean
    zip -r backups/BACKUP_DATE-`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S`.zip $(DIRECTORIES) README.txt makefile
    make
```

Comment: Yes, reading a file from a FAT12 file system works from a bootloader. It has been done by some OSes for 30+ years. If it doesn't work for you then it is a bug in your code.

Comment: I never tried to use the FAT12 file system and started by placing the binary program directly on the sectors sequentially. Does it have any disadvantages? Because it only worked on bochs and not on qemu. It seems to me there is no big reason that my code doesn't work on a physical machine. @Mich

Comment: If it works on one and not the other it is because you have coded something incorrectly. You have probably made some assumptions in the code that are not true. If you post all of your code I can probably tell you why it works in BOCHS and not QEMU and suggest a fix. If testing it on real hardware using USB you may even have to place a BIOS Parameter Block in your bootloader. There are many gotchyas in bootloader development.

Comment: I have added the code for stage 2 bootloader @MichaelPetch

Comment: Add ALL your code from all your files. Often problems can start with things that are wrong early on. Every file so that people can reproduce it. Failure to do that will likely give you no answers.

Comment: Added the entire boot code @MichaelPetch

Comment: Thanks. Can you also add the commands you use to make the kernel (A Makefile or build script etc). Knowing how you put everything together and build the disk images can also influence things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144183/discussion-between-aneesh-sharma-and-michael-petch).

Comment: I have put information into the chat. I created a small kernel that prints hello onto the screen, used your files to build os-image.img and it works. Because you hard code the drive number (`BOOT_DRIVE`) to 0 in your second stage code it will only properly load the kernel from floppy drive A: . On QEMU this worked for me: `qemu-system-i386 -fda os-image.img` . It will fail as a hard drive if I run it with `qemu-system-i386 -hda os-image.img` . If you want to boot from other drives you have to pass the boot drive to the second stage from the first stage.

Answer (score 1):

Without a filesystem, you can't load the kernel from a file.

Most legacy BIOS tutorials I've seen do not place the kernel in a file; instead they simply concatenate the bootloader and the kernel into a raw binary, and rename it as a floppy image. This way, you can directly load the kernel from the sectors of the disk.